# Poor Undo Performance: Blender 2.9

Tags: performance, memory-management, system

I'm having issues with Undo locking up Blender on the first undo action following some action.
This happens whether I remain in one mode, or on one obj. Basically say I rotate a joint and I don't like it. I undo and my blender locks up for like 6 seconds then performs the undo. If I want to undo further from there I can get like 4 or 5 more in before it locks up again. And if I commit any new action, the first undo will always lock up.

Right now all I have in my scene is a few disabled duplicate collections (for safety), a retopo'd character body mesh (10K polys), a rigify rig, and an empty. my blend file is 37mb. Blender says the scene is using 3.3GB of Memory and 3.4GB of VRAM.

I am using global undo (tried without too). was at 200 undo steps with no limit, then tried at 50 step to see if that helped, but it didnt.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

Thanks. Also, I dont see where I can add a blend file. is that not a thing?
[image]

Comment: You can use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), this site is for BSE only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encounter any problem toward Undo system, please help to file up that bug to the bug tracker in Blender develop. There is a new undo/redo system been adopted due to the old one was bulky in some situation.

---

A quick way to fix your strange behavior is to use old system instead of new one:

By checking **Developer Extras** in *Preference*-

[image]

And choose *Experiment panel* and check **undo legacy**

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it was the legacy pref or just having restarted Blender and clearing the cache but it appears to be smooth now. Thanks for that tip