# Undo aka ctrl + z is a pain on my system with Blender

Tags: edit-mode

Any idea why undoing (ctrl+z) something as simple as scaling an icosphere just kills blender? My fans spin up like crazy. Is this a bug or just how it is? I'm pretty new.

Comment: What's your spec? It might be the problem. I have 4 GB of RAMs, GeForce GT 720, and i3 CPU and they work fine

Comment: i5 6600K, 16GB Ram, GTX1080

Answer (score 1):

Consider Blender undo/redo as an automately backup system, they read all data in previous step and load all of them directly. <sub>(2.8x)</sub>

 <sub>(2.9x add some optimized method to it, see the link below)</sub> 

 <sub>(2.7x and below is another system)</sub>

- [memory management - Poor Undo Performance: Blender 2.9 - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194446/poor-undo-performance-blender-2-9)
- [⚓ T60695 Optimized per-datablock global undo](https://developer.blender.org/T60695)

Handling time will depend on your memory accessing speed and your data 'size'. In some situation, undo/redo can be bulky:

- Large amount of meshes vertices
- Low available system memory (RAM) causing constantly memory swap
- Dirty blender file with lots of abandon/orphan data chunks leaved in data
- Cumulative memory leak in process when running Blender (restart Blender)